# Do the deaths in the tutorial lock me out of "The Untouchables"?

Tags: achievements, xcom-2

Despite having already played a lot of XCOM 2, when I decided to start playing again, I was forced to do the tutorial (as the game was still installing at the time). During the tutorial, two squad members are scripted to die, since the tutorial forces you to make specific moves.

That said, there's an achievement called "The Untouchables" for beating the campaign on Commander+ without losing a single soldier. Will these two scripted deaths lock me out of that achievement for this run? That is, is it mandatory to skip the tutorial if I'm to attempt getting this achievement?

Comment: Usually these acheivement dont count scripted deaths, except if theres a way to save them in some way.

Comment: @Fredy31 that's what I was thinking, but they show up in the Fallen Soldiers memorial

Answer (score 58, accepted):

After doing some more research, it appears that doing the tutorial voids this achievement, so it's mandatory to skip it if you want to try to get "The Untouchables."

From [this thread revolving around this very subject](http://steamcommunity.com/app/268500/discussions/0/412446890547062236/):

> After some more testing I can now confirm that the 2 scripted deaths during the Tutorial count against the Untouchable Achievement (no soldier deaths).

And from [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/268500/discussions/0/412446890547960231/):

> Although Victory result says no soldier lost, and the difficulty is Commander, where is my achievement then ? You lose 2 soldiers in the tutorial and they are listed in the memorial wall, but not on the victory screen.
>
> Correct. You lost two soldiers and therefore cannot pick up that achievement

And a [third source](https://www.trueachievements.com/a223166/the-untouchables-achievement):

> this is just a heads up that if you run the tutorial mission, the soldier deaths will ruin the chance of getting this achievement. So make sure you skip the tutorial before you start down the road for this one.

Thus, it appears that you cannot get this achievement if you complete the tutorial. Despite showing 0 deaths on the ending screen, the game still takes those initial (scripted) deaths into account and does not award the achievement.

Comment: That's just dumb.

Comment: If there is a way to screw you, XCOM will find it

Comment: Yes, Achievements are, indeed, dumb :P

Comment: It was the same in XCOM 1, to be fair. At the very least they get points for being consistent ;)